# How to get all packages from an Eclipse Plug-in?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, classloader

```java
// Eclipse PDE 2022-09  
// JDK17
// I get the ClassLoader of org.eclipse.swt
ClassLoader classLoader = ......

// Try to get all packages from it
Package packages[] = classLoader.getDefinedPackages() ;
for ( Package pkg : packages ) {
    println( pkg ) ;
}

// But some packages are missing from the results, like "org.eclipse.swt.awt".
```

In this scenario, how can I get all the packages ？

Comment: Do you actually want all the packages or just the ones exported by the plugin (which is done in a different way?)

Comment: All the packages. This `classLoader` belongs to the SWT bundle, why can't it get all the packages?

Comment: As I understand it `getDefinedPackages` only returns the packages which have actually had a class loaded from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my way `getAllClassName( SWTBundle ) ;`

```
public record Package( String packageName , List<String> classes , Bundle bundle ){
        
    public Class<?> loadClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if( !classes.contains(className) ) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException("not found " + className) ;
        }
        return bundle.loadClass( packageName + "." + className ) ;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(packageName);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Package other = (Package) obj;
            return Objects.equals(packageName, other.packageName);
    }
}
    
    
public Stream<Package> getAllClassName(Bundle bundle) throws BundleException {
    BundleWiring bundleWiring = bundle.adapt(BundleWiring.class) ;
    if( bundleWiring == null ) {
        throw new BundleException( "BundleWiring is null" ) ;
    }
    Collection<String> resources = bundleWiring.listResources("/", "*.class", BundleWiring.LISTRESOURCES_RECURSE);
    List<Package> packageList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String resource : resources) {
        String className = FilenameUtils.getBaseName( resource ) ;
        String packageName = FilenameUtils.getPathNoEndSeparator( resource ).replace('/','.') ;
        int index = packageList.indexOf(new Package(packageName,null,null)) ;
        ArrayList<String> classes = null ;
        if( index == -1 ) {
            classes = new ArrayList<>() ;
            packageList.add( new Package(packageName,classes,bundle) ) ;
        }else {
            classes = (ArrayList<String>)packageList.get(index).classes ;
        }
        classes.add( className ) ;
    }
    return packageList.stream().sorted( (a,b) -> a.packageName.compareTo(b.packageName) ) ;
}
```